# IoC DI, How to I resolve deep within the core?

Tags: inversion-of-control

Everyone says that an IOC should not be static or global in any way and should be created at root. But how do I get at it deep within my code?

Lets say I have an entry point ClassA. In here I can create an instance of an IOC and register all my interfaces to concrete types etc. But what then?  Do I now start passing the IoC around ?  Surely this would violate DIP ?  None of the articles I have read discuss getting access to the Ioc and I would have thought it fundamental.  I'm sure I must be missing something very simple here :)

Lets say ClassA creates a ClassB which creates A ClassC.  Class C needs access to my resolved IDatabase.  How does it get it ? Do I have to pass the IoC all the way in ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing in the dependencies that a class needs. If Class C needs access to IDatabase then you must allow your IoC Container to pass an implementation of IDatabase into Class C, for example by having an IDatabase parameter on the Constructor for Class C.

If the IoC framework has the responsibility for creating Class C, then it also has the responsibility for giving Class C the dependencies it needs. As long as IDatabase has been registered in the IoC Container against a class which implements IDatabase, then an IDatabase parameter on Class C's constructor should be passed an implementation of IDatabase automatically.

To look at your example of ClassA creating ClassB which creates ClassC. Class A should **not** be 'newing' up an instance of ClassB using the 'new' keyword (I'm using C# or Java syntax here).

Rather, ClassA, ClassB and ClassC should all be registered with your IoC Container. If ClassA needs an instance of ClassB, then give ClassA a constructor which takes a parameter of ClassB. Your IoC Container should automatically resolve an instance of ClassB and pass it into ClassA. The same applies all the way down the chain as far as you need to go.

Using constructors (aka 'Constructor Injection') is not the only option here. You can often also use Property Injection, whereby public property setters are automatically set by your IoC Container (and there is also the much rarer 'Interface Injection'). But Constructor Injection is often the best way to go because it is then very clear exactly what dependencies a class needs before it can be instantiated; Property Injection can be unclear because a property may or may not be set by the IoC Container, depending on whether or not the property type has been registered or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how?  If we instantiate the IoC in the root, how does class B use class C ?  do we have to pass the IoC in to B in order for B to be able to use C ?

Comment: Class B can use Class C because Class B has a constructor with a parameter of Class C, and the IoC Container passes in an instance of Class C automatically when it is creating Class B.

Comment: The IoC Container should not be passed into a class; it does everything it has to do from outside the class, by giving it the dependencies it needs. This is exactly what 'Dependency Injection' means.

Comment: Holf, Class B does not have a constructor with a Class C param! I never said that.  Are you saying that I should take all the new'ing in my code and replace them with ctor parameters in their relevant classes and then register each class in the IoC in my root ?

Comment: Exactly that. Of course, you can 'new' up a class if it has no dependencies which the IoC Container looks after. For example, a simple DTO class is something you'd 'new' as and when you need it. But if a class has a dependency which the IoC Container owns, such as your IDatabase dependency example, then yes, the class which needs IDatabase should also be registered with the IoC Container.

Comment: It is tempting to access the IoC Container directly instead, for example using the 'Service Locator' pattern, whereby you put a static wrapper around your Container such that you can access it from anywhere in your code. But this is considered an anti-pattern, for reasons well explained here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ The comments on that article are also worth checking out, as people argue the point back and forth.

Comment: Holf, many thanks for the conversation, it is very helpful.  I am now struggling with the whole point of an IoC now however.  Lets say in the root, I instantiate an IoC, register all my classes with it. Dont I then have to call the ioC's Resolve to start ClassB ? and I have to know about ClassC in my root also, so why not just do it manually as in IDatabase db = new Database(); ClassC c = new ClassC(db);  ClassB b = new ClassB(c);  Whats the point of the IoC here?
Also, I read that blog post earlier, It mentions the issues with static and global that I totally get but doesnt offer alternative

Comment: I absolutely see where you're coming from. Have a look at this: http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/. IoC helps to fulfil the 'D' (Dependency inversion principle) of SOLID code design http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design). But it is a 'sum is greater than the parts' thing. In my opinion, the 'S' of SOLID, the 'Single responsibility principle', is the most important concept and the 'OLID' parts all help to achieve the 'S'.